# Why does Boruto's Karma resonate with Kawaki's

Tags: boruto

Whenever Kawaki activates his Karma, it inevitably triggers Boruto's Karma to activate. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because of the conflict Momoshiki has with Isshiki.

Answer (score 1):

Since Boruto doesn't yet have the ability to activate Karma at will so, he can't control its activation or deactivation. The only way for Boruto to activate Karma is with resonance, for now that is and he needs to be close to Kawaki as well.

The resonance is not only limited to Kawaki's karma,

> we can see that when Jigen comes to the leaf to take Kawaki back, but this time Boruto's karma resonates with Jigen's from further away.

Comment: Your response does not directly answer the question. Also, Jigen and kawaki share Kama from the same Otsutsuki, and thats why when Jigen used Kawaki to teleport to Konoha, it forcefully activated Kawaki's Kama which in turn activated Borutos